# Android LiveData<List<>> vs. List<> memory size comparison?

Tags: android, android-livedata

So I've been reading more thoroughly into `LiveData` and my curiosity was piqued.  `LiveData` can hold a list of anything, but how does that compare to a regular `List` in terms of memory allocation.  I know generally it depends on what is being stored.  A `List<int>` can be larger than a `List<float>`, if there's only 1 float and a 100 ints.

But, for example, lets say I had a `LiveData<List<int>>` of 10 phone numbers, and a `List<int>` of the same phone numbers.  Would the `LiveData` take up more memory?

I know `LiveData` has a specific purpose in keeping the UI updated(I'm probably not articulating that accurately) and needs an `Observer`, whereas a plain `List` is easier to work with but can't meet the need `LiveData` fulfills.

Or do most devices these days simply have enough memory that it's basically a moot point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would the LiveData take up more memory?

For the same underlying list, yes.  It's always going to occupy some space beyond the data it contains.  Look at the source code to get a sense of what it actually adds on top of the contained data object.

You're probably overthinking it.  If you have a problem with running out of memory, it's almost certainly not because of any LiveData.  Your list itself is likely the bigger issue, and other parts of the core Android runtime are going to dwarf the size of your LiveData and its contents.